# Video not playing ios app

Tags: ios

I am trying to get a video to play when clicking on a UITabBar item. I followed this tutorial: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Video_Playback_from_within_an_iOS_5_iPhone_Application

Whenever I click the UITabBar item, it just shows the normal view, it doesn't add a movie view. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"m4v"]];
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                initWithContentURL:url];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayer];

moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}
```

I'm also getting the following errors:

```
2013-01-26 15:21:08.243 Smart Mower[61339:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling        autoplay for pause
2013-01-26 15:21:08.244 Smart Mower[61339:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2013-01-26 15:21:08.260 Smart Mower[61339:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping   autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)
```

Can someone help me out? 
Thanks!

Comment: How did you come out on this?

Answer (score 0):

Hello try adding a few of these things.

1) Make sure your movie is being added during run time in your copy bundle resources under build phases.

2) Try adding the code to for your declaration like this:

```
            NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"movie" ofType:@"mp4"];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
            moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
            moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame;
            moviePlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
            moviePlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
           [moviePlayer.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
           [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                           name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayer.moviePlayer];

            [moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];
```

Let me know how you come out.

Comment: I made sure the video was being added. Replaced my code with the code above and these are the errors I get when I click the UITabBar. I get the same errors as in the original post and then I get errors regarding CGContext... `invalid context 0x0`

Comment: yes i did. I solved this using a different method though. Thanks for your help!